# Why Won't, and How, Will my UL get centered inside of a navbar DIV?

Tags: css, html-lists, center

I'm creating a "flat design" website, and for my navbar, I would like it to extend to the width of the div directly beneath it. I have done that. But, for the navigation itself, I used a list. The list is displayed inline as blocks, but I want the UL to be centered in the nav DIV no matter what width it is. It will be a dynamic width. Here is my CSS:

```
div#header{
    width:982px;
    height:160px;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
}
div#nav{
    width:auto;
    height:43px;
    padding-top:15px;
    padding-right:15px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    background-color:rgba(100,100,100,0.3);
    border-left-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    border-right-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    border-right-width:1px;
    border-right-style:solid;
    border-left-width:1px;
    border-left-style:solid;
    border-top-width:1px;
    border-top-style:solid;
    border-top-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
#nav ul{
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0;
}
#nav ul li{
    width:48px;
    height:48px;
    margin-left:15px;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:#000000;
    padding:0;
}
#nav ul li a{
    z-index:10;
}
#googleplus{
    width:48px;
    height:48px;
    background-image:url('images/googleplus.png');
    display:block;
}
#facebook{
    width:48px;
    height:48px;
    background-image:url('images/facebook.png');
    display:block;
}
#twitter{
    width:48px;
    height:48px;
    background-image:url('images/twitter.png');
    display:block;
}
#youtube{
    width:48px;
    height:48px;
    background-image:url('images/youtube.png');
    display:block;
}
#minecraft{
    width:48px;
    height:48px;
    background-image:url('images/minecraft.png');
    display:block;
}
#nav ul li#googleplus{
    background-color:#d34836;
    transition:background-color;
    transition-duration:0.17s;
}
#nav ul li#googleplus:hover{
    background-color:#c23725;
}
#nav ul li#facebook{
    background-color:#3b5998;
    transition:background-color;
    transition-duration:0.17s;
}
#nav ul li#facebook:hover{
    background-color:#2a4887;
}
#nav ul li#twitter{
    background-color:#4099ff;
    transition:background-color;
    transition-duration:0.17s;
}
#nav ul li#twitter:hover{
    background-color:#3188ee;
}
#nav ul li#youtube{
    background-color:#de443e;
    transition:background-color;
    transition-duration:0.17s;
}
#nav ul li#youtube:hover{
    background-color:#bc221c;
}
#nav ul li#minecraft{
    background-color:#5e5645;
    transition:background-color;
    transition-duration:0.17s;
}
#nav ul li#minecraft:hover{
    background-color:#4d4534;
}
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="logo">
    </div>
    <div id="nav">
        <ul>
            <li id="facebook" ><a id="facebook" href="#" ></a></li>
            <li id="twitter" ><a id="twitter" href="#" ></a></li>
            <li id="youtube" ><a id="youtube" href="#" ></a></li>
            <li id="minecraft" ><a id="minecraft" href="#" ></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can someone figure out a way to center the UL?

P.S. I've already tried margin:0 auto; so don't answer with that.

Comment: -1, isolate the issue

Comment: please filter the code to the relevant parts..

Comment: I've already isolated the issue.

Comment: I've filtered out the code

Comment: Interesting, background colors and transitions are isolating the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't use Flexible Box Model or Flexbox?

You will make a layout very fast and simple.

Add these classes in your parent element, (I mean in the `nav` element):

```
<nav id="nav" class="p-flexbox flex-hcc">
 <ul>
  <!-- The content -->
 </ul>
</nav>
```

Where:

1. **p-flexbox** means *parent-flexbox*
2. **flex-hcc** means *flex-horizontal-center-center*

And in your CSS file, you have to put these rules:

```
.p-flexbox {
   display: -webkit-box;
   display: -moz-box;
   display: box;
}

.flex-hcc {
   -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
      -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
           box-orient: horizontal;

   -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -moz-box-pack: center;
           box-pack: center;

   -webkit-box-align: center;
      -moz-box-align: center;
           box-align: center;
}
```

Here's an example: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hcNS9/)

Like I said in another posts, **THIS IS A BOX MODEL UNDER REVISION**, so be careful!

Cheers,
Leo

Comment: Please do not promote the use of Flexbox without also providing the standard properties.  Those are all from the deprecated 2009 draft.

Comment: You have right. Those properties are deprecated. Thanks for the information. In a few I'll change all my posts with Flexbox how answer. Cheers, Leo

Answer (score 2):

#### display:inline-block

You can use the display:inline-block,like this:

```
#nav ul{
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
  **/*to center*/
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0;
  letter-spacing: -4px;
  word-spacing: -4px;**
}
#nav ul li{
    width:48px;
    height:48px;
    margin-left:15px;
    background-color:#000000;
    padding:0;
  
  /*to center*/
  **display: inline-block;
  *display: inline;
  zoom:1;
  letter-spacing: normal;  
  word-spacing: normal;
  font-size: 12px;**
}
```

please view the [demo](http://codepen.io/airen/pen/Huyrm).

#### float

you can use the float ande position, like this:

```
#nav{
    /*to center*/
    **width:100%;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;**
    height:43px;
    padding: 15px 15px 5px 0;
    background-color:rgba(100,100,100,0.3);
    border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    border-bottom: none;
}
#nav ul{
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
  /*to center*/
    **clear: left;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;/*整个分页向右边移动宽度的50%*/
    text-align: center;**
}
#nav ul li{
    width:48px;
    height:48px;
    margin-left:15px;
    background-color:#000000;
    padding:0;
  
  /*to center*/
  **display: block;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  right: 50%;/*将每个分页项向左边移动宽度的50%*/**
}
```

please view the [demo](http://codepen.io/airen/pen/mpjen).

#### CSS3 fit-content

and you can use the css3 fit-content,like this:

```
#nav ul{
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
  /*to center*/
  **width: -moz-fit-content;
  width:-webkit-fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;**
}
#nav ul li{
    width:48px;
    height:48px;
    margin-left:15px;
    background-color:#000000;
    padding:0;
  
  /*to center*/
  **float: left;**
}
```

please view the [demo](http://codepen.io/airen/pen/tkEKo).
You can also use other methods, for example: `display: table` and `display: flex`; if you want to know, how to use other methods, please click [here](http://www.w3cplus.com/css/elements-horizontally-center-with-css.html).